# Como transferir uma lista de uma view para o próximo Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Bom dia, tudo bem?
A linguagem é C#. Preciso transferir uma lista da View Exibida abaixo para a próxima Action para validar os checkboxes. Mas acontece que já tentei de muitas formas e todas, a lista foi zerada ou nula, ou seja perdeu a referencia. Como faço para transferir no parâmetro da próxima Action sem perder a referência.
Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class VendaSupermercadoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: VendaSupermercado
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new ModeloProdutosVenda();
            var listaProdutosVenda = new List<ModeloProdutosVenda>();
            listaProdutosVenda = model.ListaProdutosVenda();
            TempData["listaProdutosVenda"] = listaProdutosVenda;
            return View("Index", listaProdutosVenda);
        }
        public ActionResult EscolherProdutos(List<ModeloProdutosVenda> listaProdutosVenda = TempData["listaProdutosVenda"])
        {

            return View("InserirQuantidades");
        }
    }
}
```

View com as caixas de seleção CheckBox

```
@using WebApplication1.Models;
@model List<ModeloProdutosVenda>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("EscolherProdutos", "VendaSupermercado"))
        {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Comprar:</th>
                <th>Nome do Produto:</th>
                <th>Valor do Produto:</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var produto in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td><input name="@produto.Checked" type="checkbox" value="@produto.NomeProduto"/></td>
                <td>@produto.NomeProduto</td>
                <td>R$ @produto.ValorProduto</td>
            </tr>
                }
        </table>
        <input type="submit"/>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Para validar os checkboxes marcados na Action correspondente ao formulário

Answer (score -1):

Acho que um script pode te ajudar

se a intenção é passar se um checkBox está marcado ou não você pode utilizar assim:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#sim", function (e) {
                var contador = @ViewBag.Contador;
                let myArray = new Array(contador);
                for (var i = 0; i <= contador; i++) {
                    let checkbox = $('#' + i);
                    if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
                        myArray[i] = document.getElementById(i).value;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Nesse meu script eu executo minha função quando uma ação click é gerada em um botão de id sim, na função eu criei um array que recebe o tamanho da minha viewBag contador(que representada a quantidade checks que tenho em minha view), depois executo um for onde eu vou verificar quais checkBox estão marcados e para facilitar o id de cada checkBox é referente ao seu número no contador, é caso esse checkBox esteja marcado eu passo o seu valor para o meu array.

após o array ficar carregado você pode tratar esses valores como bem quiser, pode envia-los via ajax para o controlador ou pode atribuir o seu valor a um campo dentro do seu form.

Não sei se era esse o seu problema realmente.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi muito bem o propósito de enviar a lista de volta para o controller, porque essas informações o controller já possui. Essa lista vai ser editada pelo usuário?

De qualquer forma, normalmente, os dados são enviados do navegador para o controller por 2 formas:

- Ajax (pelo código JavaScript)
- Método POST (através de formulário)

No seu caso, acho mais adequado usar POST

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Vai sim, o usuário irá definir se a variável Checked é true ir false, e eu preciso validar, na Action do Formulário irá ser validada